# angularJS filter not filtering data

Tags: angularjs, laravel, filter

I have a json response for a test Todo application so I can learn AngularJS here is the Json response:

```
{"id":"1","text":"Et aut optio et enim necessitatibus magni voluptatem.","due_date":"1970-08-04 00:00:00","priority":"2","created_at":"2014-09-15 01:26:52","updated_at":"2014-09-15 01:26:52"}
```

Then I have angular loop through all the responses and create the todo table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Todo</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <td>{{ todo.text }}</td>
            <td>{{ todo.priority }}</td>
            <td>{{todo.due_date | date:mediumDate}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Everything works fine except the date:mediumDate filter the date in the table still shows up time stamp style not the filtered format. What could be causing it to fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `mediumDate` as a String so do `date:'mediumDate'`

As later noted, the date string that you are using is not a recognized ISO 8601 date format by AngularJs, so to make it work with the same data you need to either send json with a standard date format or parse it yourself.  If you want to parse the date string  you have above, you can use this code:

```
  $scope.parseTheDate = function(dateString) {
    if (dateString) {
      var properlyFormattedDate = dateString.split(" ").join("T");
      return new Date(properlyFormattedDate);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
```

and combine it with the html:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <td>{{ todo.text }}</td>
        <td>{{ todo.priority }}</td>
        <td>{{ parseTheDate(todo.due_date) | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
    </tr>
```

working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xDhCzpYEQOoflKLs3pSq?p=preview

Comment: mediumDate is a filter I got it from the angularJS docs;however, I tried your solution but it still didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: where is mediumDate declared then? is it associated with your controller's scope? is it a global variable?

Comment: Actually the other problem is that `1970-08-04 00:00:00` is not a date string format that angular understands.  If you use the format `1970-08-04T00:00:00` it will work. You can either send the json with the correctly formatted date string or create a custom date parser

Comment: @beauXjames mediumDate is a predefined localizable format defined in angular.

Comment: @JoseM the OP can in fact use 'mediumDate' as the doc state: 'mediumDate': equivalent to 'MMM d, y' for en_US locale (e.g. Sep 3, 2010) where as 'medium': equivalent to 'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a' for en_US locale (e.g. Sep 3, 2010 12:05:08 PM)

Comment: @JaredReeves you are correct, I missed that format furthur down the page, I will update my answer